# How can I use a function parameter as a mongoose query?

Tags: html, express, mongoose, pug

The code is as follows...

```
function getqueried(operand, a, b, c, d, e){  

   console.log('queriedobjects length: ' + queriedgameobjects.length);
   return GameModel.find({$or:[{"ho": {operand: a}},{"dro": {operand: b}},{"ao": {operand: c}},{"home": {operand: d}},{"away": {operand: e}}]}).then((users) => {
    users.forEach((user) => {
      queriedgameobjects.push(user);
      
    });    
  })}
```

instead of choosing the lge/gte on the code, I would like to choose it dynamically from a select form on the pug template.

But it never runs. It doesnt even give an error. in the pug template, I have used this

```
select(name="select")
        option(value="$gt" name="larger") Larg than
        option(value="$lt" name="less") Less than
```

and when I invoce the function in the route, I use

```
    getqueried(req.body.select, blah blah)
```

But it doesnt work and the problem is that it doesnt even give an error. It just loads the /results page for ever!

Any help?
thank you all!

Comment: any ```console.log``` msg from ```getqueried``` ? If no, check those functions which calls ```getqueried```  ?

Comment: Nothing, unfortunately! Because it doesnt even load the routed page with the results :/